# Firebase Fire store database replacing all data to single one

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an error. when the user uploads his image.  the other data were gone and only the profile URI is visible.

Currently, I have 5 strings

- name
- email
- password
- profile(image URI)
- refer id
- coins

However, when a user uploads their profile photo, all the data is removed.

showing only the profile image URI

I have attached the code here

```
private void updateUserProfile() {
    Map<String,String > profile = new HashMap<>();
    profile.put("profile",imageUri.toString());

    database
            .collection("Users") // the path of users.
            .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) // to update in the current users.
        //    .update(user)
            .set(profile)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                 Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Photo Updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers. I already solved the problem. I have attached the codes below.

private void updateUserProfile() {

```
  Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<>();

  profile.put("profile", imageUri.toString());



    final DocumentReference sDoc = database.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
    database.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {


        @Override
        public Void apply(@NonNull  Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(sDoc);


            transaction.update(sDoc, profile);
          //  transaction.update(sDoc, "name", binding.nameBox.getText() );

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just looking to update a single field when can do so without using any Map values.

```
firestore.collection("YOUR_COLLECTION").document(user.getUid()).update("profile", imageUri.toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `.set(profile)`, you're replacing the existing data with whatever is in `profile`. If you want to merge the values in `profile` with any existing data in the document, use `.update(profile)` instead.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [updating data in a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I have already got it from firebase update data from firebase developer docs.